# Customize TableRow with Material UI component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI table example and trying to customize the rows to have my own component to replace the default row.I want to have some margin between the rows and a shadow (using elevation prop of Paper element). This is what I achieved so far:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';

const MyPaper = (item) => {
  return (
    <Paper
      elevation={6}>
      {item}
    </Paper>
  );
};

const List = () => {
  const items = ['a', 'b'];

  return (     
    <div style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}>
      <TableContainer>
        <Table aria-label="simple table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {items.map(item => (
              <TableRow key={item} component={() => MyPaper(item)}>
                <TableCell>{item}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{item}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{item}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{item}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{item}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </div>
  )
}

export default List
```

but the result is being applied only in the first column. How do I fix this to have my custom row to occupy the entire table space?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with withstyles property of Material-UI, you can arrange Paper or other MUI components to give them classes and arrange them in styles variable:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import { WithStyles } from '@material-ui/core'


const styles = theme => ({
...theme,
Row:  {
margin: 10 
      }
})

const List = () => {
  const items = ['a', 'b'];
  const {classes} = this.props
  return (     
    <div style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}>
      <TableContainer>
        <Table aria-label="simple table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {items.map(item => (
              <TableRow key={item} className={classes.Row}>
                <TableCell>{item}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{item}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{item}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{item}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{item}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </div>
  )
}

export default withStyles(styles)(List)
```